# Is it possible to have a map of map in MapState?

Tags: join, streaming, apache-flink, flink-streaming

```
private MapState<String, EventsHistory> eventsMap = null;
 
public void processElement2(Event event,
                            Context context,
                            Collector<JoinedEvent> collector) throws Exception {
    String name = event.getExperimentName();
    if (eventsMap.get(name) == null) {
         eventsMap.put(name, new EventsHistory());
    }
    eventsMap.get(name).put(event.getEventTime(), event);
}

class EventsHistory {

    private final Map<Long, Event> events = new HashMap<>();

    public Map<Long, Event> getEvents() {
        return events;
    }

    public void put(final Long eventTime, final Event event) {
        events.put(eventTime, event);
    }
}
```

I have the above code and would like to use Flink's `MapState` to maintain a map of maps.
When I test this locally, I can see the state update fine. But when I run it in a cluster, the `eventsMap` is always empty.

Is it valid to use a map of maps in `MapState`? Is there a better way to achieve this?

As an alternate, I tried the below version, where I do the grouping myself. Strangely enough this works.

```
private MapState<EventKey, Event> assignmentEventsMap = null;

public final class EventKey {

    private String name;
    private long eventTime;
}

    public void processElement2(Event event,
                                Context context,
                                Collector<JoinedEvent> collector) throws Exception {
        String name = event.getExperimentName();
        eventsMap
                .put(new EventKey(event.getName(), event.getEventTime()),
                        event);
    }
```

Comment: The code looks correct, I don't think it should cause problems with updates, so most probably there is some other issue out there.

Comment: I have updated the description with an alternate approach (though less efficient) that works.

Comment: How have you keyed the two streams that are connected?

Comment: Yes, they are keyed. As you mentioned below, could this be an issue due to the different parallelism settings?

Answer (score 0):

The code you have shared is difficult to understand, but perhaps you have misunderstood what MapState is. ValueState provides a sharded key/value store, distributed across the cluster. MapState gives you a sharded key/value store, where the values themselves are nested Maps.

In other words, MapState is always map of maps. You ended up trying to create a map of maps of maps -- which is one level too far.

I'm assuming you are trying to build this structure, where you effectively have a map from experiment names to nested maps of timestamps to events:

`name -> (time -> event)`

Assuming that your stream of events has already been keyed by the experiment name, then rather than using `MapState<String, EventsHistory> eventsMap`, what you really want is `MapState<Long, Event> eventsMap`, and rather than

```java
eventsMap.get(name).put(event.getEventTime(), event);
```

you should be doing

```java
eventsMap.put(event.getEventTime(), event);
```

See [the tutorial about ValueState](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/learn-flink/etl.html#an-example-with-keyed-state) and [an example using MapState](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/learn-flink/event_driven.html#example) in the Flink docs for more background how to work with these mechanisms.

Comment: You are right about the "map from experiment names to nested maps of timestamps to events". But my events are keyed on a different attribute. So I need to maintain this structure for multiple names. Also, I cannot move this attribute into the key because I am working on a join of two streams and the other stream doesn't have this attribute.

Comment: Have you considered doing a broadcast join? In some cases that will perform better.

Comment: I haven't. Let me take a look. As for the MapState<String, Map<Long, Event>>, I just want to understand if this will not work or I might be missing something.

Comment: Also puzzled since the same code works on local Flink app but not in a cluster

Comment: Did you change the parallelism between when you ran it locally and in the cluster?

Comment: Your code is doing things I don't understand. I would need to see more of the app in order to figure out what's going on.

Comment: Yes, local has parallelism 1, while cluster has 5